# Web Api Dependency Injection In Custom AuthorizeAttribute Via Unity Doesn't Work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container, authorize-attribute

I've asked this question and marked as duplicated but there is a problem in dependency injection in custom AuthorizeAttribute in my design. I've tried 
several codes from some same answers. Everything is working correctly except attributes, _authenticationService is always being null. My code:

```
public class AuthenticateAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   [Dependency]
   private IAuthenticationService _authenticationService { get; set; }

   public AuthenticateAttribute()
   {
        //_authenticationService is null here, even tried this code too:
        //
   }
```

**Test 1**

*UnityActionFilterProvider*

```
public class UnityActionFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityActionFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration,
        HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        foreach (IActionFilter actionFilter in container.ResolveAll<IActionFilter>())
        {
            // TODO: Determine correct FilterScope
            yield return new FilterInfo(actionFilter, FilterScope.Global);
        }
    }
}
```

*RegisterComponents*

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

        var providers = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders().ToList();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider), new UnityActionFilterProvider(container));
        var defaultprovider = providers.First(p => p is ActionDescriptorFilterProvider);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Remove(typeof(IFilterProvider), defaultprovider);
}
```

*Global.asax*

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

**Test 2**

*UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider *

```
public class UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<FilterAttribute> GetControllerAttributes(
                ControllerContext controllerContext,
                ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {

        var attributes = base.GetControllerAttributes(controllerContext,
                                                      actionDescriptor);
        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(attribute.GetType(), attribute);
        }

        return attributes;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<FilterAttribute> GetActionAttributes(
                ControllerContext controllerContext,
                ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {

        var attributes = base.GetActionAttributes(controllerContext,
                                                  actionDescriptor);
        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(attribute.GetType(), attribute);
        }

        return attributes;
    }
}
```

*RegisterComponents*

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        var oldProvider = System.Web.Mvc.FilterProviders.Providers.Single(f => f is System.Web.Mvc.FilterAttributeFilterProvider);
        System.Web.Mvc.FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(oldProvider);
        var provider = new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container);
        container.RegisterInstance<UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider>(provider);
        System.Web.Mvc.FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);
}
```

*Global.asax*

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```